# Different borders for the cell in tcpdf by "setlinestyle"

Tags: border, cell, tcpdf

In library TCPDF. How can I set different borders by command "setlinestyle",  to make the cell looks like f.e. this:

**css**

```
/* top */
border-top-width="1" 
border-top-style="solid" 
border-top-color="rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)"
/* right */
border-right-width="2" 
border-right-style="dotted" 
border-right-color="rgba(255, 0, 255, 1)" 
/* bottom */ 
border-bottom-width="3" 
border-bottom-style="solid" 
border-bottom-color="rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)"
/* left */
border-left-width="4" 
border-left-style="solid" 
border-left-color="rgba(255, 0, 255, 1)"
```

**PHP command with one style for all borders**

```
$pdf->SetLineStyle(array('width' => 0.5, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 4, 'color' => array(255, 0, 0)));

$text="DUMMY";
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, $text, 1, 1, 'L', 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When creating the cell you can set each border to a different line style individually by passing them as a grouped array for the border parameter.  For example (note that this does not exactly match your CSS above.)

```
$complex_cell_border = array(
   'T' => array('width' => 1, 'color' => array(0,255,0), 'dash' => 4, 'cap' => 'butt'),
   'R' => array('width' => 2, 'color' => array(255,0,255), 'dash' => '1,3', 'cap' => 'round'),
   'B' => array('width' => 3, 'color' => array(0,0,255), 'dash' => 0, 'cap' => 'square'),
   'L' => array('width' => 4, 'color' => array(255,0,255), 'dash' => '3,1,0.5,2', 'cap' => 'butt'),
);
//Where T,B,R, and L are Top, Bottom, Right and Left respectively.

$pdf->Cell(0,0,"Dummy text, more dummy text!", $complex_cell_border);
```

They can also be grouped so you're not having to provide the same style multiple times.  For example, here we have parallel borders share the same style.

```
$complex_cell_border = array(
   'TB' => array('width' => 1, 'color' => array(0,255,0), 'dash' => 4, 'cap' => 'butt'),
   'RL' => array('width' => 2, 'color' => array(255,0,255), 'dash' => '1,3', 'cap' => 'round'),
);

$pdf->Cell(0,0,"Dummy text, more dummy text!", $complex_cell_border);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time to make this answer. I already found this solution and made it in my code. It works fine... Thank you anyway, and your code is right. THX :)

Comment: @EPB Excellent, well written answer. Thanks. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution for the above question, if you want each row different borders:

```
$tpdf->MultiCell(12,15,'','L','C',1,0);   // Left border only 
$tpdf->MultiCell(12,15,'','LR','C',1,0);  // Left and Right border only 
$tpdf->MultiCell(12,15,'','LRB','C',1,0); // Left,Right and Bottom border only 
$tpdf->MultiCell(12,15,'','LRBT','C',1,0);// Full border
```