# How fix border in TcPDF writer in PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: php, tcpdf, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

I've a PhpSpreadsheet process to export data to XLSX and PDF. I'm using TcPDF as PDF writer. But TcPDF has a problem to convert/translate border style.

**Xlsx export**

[image]

**TcPDF export**

[image]

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: You should post an issue [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues)

Comment: I'll copy to the repository. thks

Comment: Done @JeroenHeier https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/548

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can help you better.

Comment: I create a simples XLSX worksheet, with border format, and using TcPDF writer to export XLSX structure in PDF. Get any example and use TcPDF as writer https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to use TcPDF's [`SetLineStyle()`](http://microknowledge.com/tcpdf/doc/com-tecnick-tcpdf/TCPDF.html#methodSetLineStyle) (see [example 35](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/examples/example_035.php)):

```
$pdf->SetLineStyle(array('width' => 0.5, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 4, 'color' => array(255, 0, 0)));
$text="DUMMY";
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, $text, 1, 1, 'L', 1, 0);
```

- if you want to create complex border styles for individual cells check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730636/different-borders-for-the-cell-in-tcpdf-by-setlinestyle)
- or see [example 48](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/examples/example_048.php) if you use HTML tables.

Alternatively, try [`SetLineWidth(1.0)`](http://microknowledge.com/tcpdf/doc/com-tecnick-tcpdf/TCPDF.html#methodSetLineWidth).

Comment: The convertion from Worksheet to PDF use generic HTML. But in TcPDF border is big. mPDF is normal.

Comment: Have you tried to specify a line style for the entire table?

Comment: I try set $pdf->SetLineStyle(1) before convertion HTML (from Worksheet) to PDF, but not change.

Comment: I think this is not the right way to use SetLineStyle() since it requires an array as param. See http://microknowledge.com/tcpdf/doc/com-tecnick-tcpdf/TCPDF.html#methodSetLineStyle

Comment: I'll fix this. THks

Comment: SetLineStyle and SetLineWidth don't  change anything :(